# how to toggle on SideBar for all the dropdown in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a "Sidebar" component in which I would like to toggle 'active' class onClick of each Menu item.

How can i use the jquery code from the code `https://codepen.io/amsteldroid/pen/NoBYye` and use it Reactjs

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-dawn-t0pjx?file=/src/App.js)

As i am new in React world as i dont want to use Jquery in React how can i use this chunk of  in my jsx.

Do i have to use useRef

```
$('.sub-menu ul').hide();
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("100");
    $(this).find(".right").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This original answer was submitted before the asker clarified that they were looking for a dynamic navbar generation.

---

The React tutorial will provide a greater overview of the concepts used in this answer, but I'm hopeful that this small demo will give you enough to get started.

To show / hide content, you'll need to know **hooks** and **conditional jsx**.

Hooks are a new way to manage state in React. Here's an example:

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  const [ showSettings, setShowSettings ] = useState(false);
```

By default, the state variable `showSettings` is set to false. Other functions can modify `showSettings` using `setShowSettings(valuehere)`.

In the example below, `showSettings` is updated when the nav `<a>` tag is clicked. Like so:

```
<a href="#settings" onClick={() => setShowSettings(!showSettings)}>
```

In JSX, you can use conditional logic like so:

```
{(showSettings ? <p> I'm active! </p> : <p> I'm not active </p>})
```

The brackets are necessary to call javascript in the return function. The first item is a conditional (`showSettings`, either true or false in this case), and then we have the conditions. What follows `?` is if `showSettings` is true, what follows `:` is if `showSettings` is false.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";



export default function App() {

  const [ showSettings, setShowSettings ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav class="animated bounceInDown">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#message">Messages</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
          <a href="#settings" onClick={() => setShowSettings(!showSettings)}>
            Settings<div class="fa fa-caret-down right"></div>
          </a>
          {(showSettings ?
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#settings">Account</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#settings">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#settings">Secruity &amp; Privacy</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#settings">Password</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#settings">Notification</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          : '' )}

        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
          <a href="#message">
            Help<div class="fa fa-caret-down right"></div>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#settings">FAQ's</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#settings">Submit a Ticket</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#settings">Network Status</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#message">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-63755719-ul-show-hide-6sk2x

Comment: That means for each submenus i had to call different state variable show its properties true and false. Suppose i had 50 sub menus so i had to use 50 different state variable. I don't think its a right approach. Even your code handles only for ```setting``` what about ```message```

Comment: I agree this is not the best approach, but this is the answer to your question about showing and hiding a <ul>. With these ingredients and a bit of functional programming, it can be scaled to toggle any number of elements in your nav. Two options: (1) update your question with a narrowed focus and these constraints, with specificity provided to building a nav bar or (2) open a new question.

Comment: What you suggest should i open a new or you will help me out in this one? If i update the question..

Comment: Could you tell? how to use toggle properties

Comment: @akhi21 yes, I am close to a solution. It will be posted soon.

Answer (score 0):

The question was updated and is now asking for dynamic navbar functionality. Namely, that when React is given Navbar data it will (1) dynamically generate the navbar content and (2) dynamically open and close children.

First we need to write the navbar data. If you are gathering this from an endpoint, make sure your API data is restructured as follows:

```
const NavBarData = [
  {
    name: "Profile",
    href: "",
    children: []
  },
  {
    name: "Messages",
    href: "",
    children: []
  },
  {
    name: "Settings",
    href: "",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Account"
      },
      {
        name: "Profile"
      },
      {
        name: "Security"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Help",
    href: "",
    children: [
      {
        name: "FAQs"
      },
      {
        name: "Submit a Ticket"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Logout",
    href: "",
    children: []
  }
];

export default NavBarData;
```

Next, we want the React application to digest this data and produce the desired functionality. To do this I used `object deconstruction` and `mapping` to iterate over the `NavBarData` to generate the `<ul>` / `<li>` frame that you want.

Parents are buttons and `onClick` then modify a `open` array hook so that their name is included / excluded. You will know if they are included / excluded in the array when the button color changes to red in this example.

Finally using `styled-components` I fed the `open` hook to each parent UL and the css dynamically changes based on whether the parents name is in the `open` array.

I did not move your custom CSS into the styled components but it is simple to do, you should be able to just copy / paste as you see fit.

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-63755719-ul-show-hide-6sk2x?file=/src/App.js

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import NavBarData from "./NavBarData.js";

const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState([]);

  const toggleNavbar = (e) => {
    // this function will get the parent nav's name from its data-value attribute
    // then it checks if open has the parent in the array; if so, it is deleted
    // else it is added

    // each individaul parentUL will receive the open hook
    // and if its name is in the open var, it will dynamically show or hide its children

    let current = e.target.getAttribute("data-value");

    if (open.includes(current)) {
      var newOpen = [...open].filter((e) => e !== current);
    } else {
      var newOpen = [...open, current];
    }

    setOpen(newOpen);
  };

  const NavItems = ({ data }) =>
    data.map((parent, i) => (
      <ParentUL
        key={i}
        name={parent.name}
        open={open.includes(parent.name) ? true : false}
      >
        <ParentButton onClick={toggleNavbar} data-value={parent.name}>
          {parent.name}
        </ParentButton>
        <ChildUL>
          {parent.children.map((child, i) => (
            <ChildLI key={i}>{child.name}</ChildLI>
          ))}
        </ChildUL>
      </ParentUL>
    ));

  return <NavItems data={NavBarData} />;
};

const ParentUL = styled.ul`
  /* your existing css should go here */

  /* if the parent's name is in 'open' hook, then show its children*/
  & ul li {
    display: ${(props) => (props.open ? "block" : "none")};
  }
  & button {
    background: ${(props) => (props.open ? "red" : "yellow")};
  }
`;

const ParentButton = styled.button`
  width: 200px;
`;

const ChildUL = styled.ul`
  /* your existing css should go here */
`;

const ChildLI = styled.li`
  /* your existing css should go here */
`;

export default App;
```

Comment: @Akhi21 did this answer your question?